# How should I wire up a yurt?

Tags: electrical, yurt

This yurt 30 ft. diameter; area is 700 sq. ft. ; circumference is 90 ft.

The walls are lath lattice covered with canvas. There's no interior wall space to run Romex like a regular house. You can't attach electrical boxes to the walls, either.

[image]

Some yurts have interior partition walls that hold wiring (and plumbing!) but not this one. 
One option is to put flush-mount outlets in the floor. These seem to cost about $50 / ea., which adds up when you're talking about one every 12 ft. around the perimeter. They also require cutting rather large holes in the floor.

Outlets aren't the only concern: some ambient lighting from lamps hanging from the rafters are also on the docket. How to bring the wiring up the rafters?

Some yurts have additional framing in the form of 2x4s under each rafter:

[image: Snow and Wind Kit]

This yurt does not have them, but I could add a few them as needed to support wiring infrastructure. I imagine I could run EMT up from the floor to a recep, then up to a light switch, and then up to the rafters for lighting.

How should I proceed?

Comment: What is this Yurt thing gonna do?  A camp, living space, storage, voodoo hut??????  Maybe some temp construction outlets and festoon lighting? How perminent do you want them to be?

Comment: @shirlockhomes: Dungeon. Actually, living space: bed, sofa, desk. One day, a kitchen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind for me, if you don't want to do the floor mounted outlets, is to run the boxes like you would in an exterior deck.  Use weather tight conduit to exterior outlet boxes.  And put the entire circuit on a GFCI breaker.

Here are a few product links:

- [Conduit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KGD0FQ)
- [T-Fitting](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQLV1K)
- [J-Box](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BPC2N2)
- [Cover](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQRGCI)

Comment: Is it safe to use PVC conduit / fittings / boxes indoors? I believe there's a fire issue with them. Weathertight is still attractive, because rain can come in an open window.

Comment: I should add the two disclaimers that the amazon links are just for ideas (the product pages were very light on specifics to know if the conduit was even suitable for electrical) and also that I've never built one of these Yurts.  Fire rated electrical PVC does exist.  But I'm not sure if any of this is suitable for living space, I was picturing something closer to an enclosed porch.

Comment: Bmitch is on the right track.  i'd be tempted to use 3/4 plastic conduit and plastic conduit glue connect boxes.  You can bend the conduit around the curves with a heat box or with hot water. Run

Comment: Run Romex or THHN in the conduits, plumb it up with T's etc to lights, use weather tite covers if you like etc. You can secure it to the floor with plastic clamps and uprights with ty-raps.  Get creative, I don't think there are any instructions for this application.  Leave it to you to come up with this one!  lol.