# What's the appropriate cable type along exposed rafters?

Tags: electrical, yurt

This is a followup to [my previous, more general question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7979/how-should-i-wire-up-a-yurt).

I installed (exposed) 2"x4" studs at strategic locations. These provide a mounting point for metal boxes, and EMT carries the wire up from the crawlspace, through the metal boxes, and up to ceiling height.

Example: (click for full-size)
[image: Outlet]

I want to wire light fixtures in the ceilings. Bending EMT between fixtures' boxes is one option, but because of the unusual shape of the ceiling, I think I'd rather use something flexible. I believe the options are:

- NM cable (aka Romex).
- AC cable (aka BX).
- MC cable.

I think NM is prohibited by code because the rafters are exposed - the cable needs to be protected, right?

Which is the right choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jay, I think you can use NM for this application as long as you do not cross beam. Cross beam refers to bridging between collar ties or floor joists across the bottom of said members, as opposed to drilling mid member and lacing the cable through the holes or following parameter beams and extending inward for each fixture along sides of 2X4's

My first choice would be BX or greenfield plastic coated flex raceway. EMT would be great, but maybe a little impracticable for your application.